# Android app for radio streaming mms:// howto

Tags: android, streaming, audio-streaming, live-streaming, internet-radio

I'm trying to create an Android app which streams a radio channel. 
This is the link for the radio streaming: mms://89.96.234.34:8000 
How can I use this on Android?
This is my MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("mms://89.96.234.34:8000");
    MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri).start();
} }
```

I added: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>` in the manifest, and when I launch the app I have a null pointer exception on line 16:

```
        MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri).start();
```

Comment: Do you have the answer to your question ? Do mms urls work with MediaPlayer ?

Answer (score 1):

Hello i also have an app like this and i use it like this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("mms://89.96.234.34:8000");
MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, uri).start();
```

Comment: Tried that, but I have a Null Pointer Exception on the second line (MediaPlayer.Create ...) should I add something in the activity or in the manifest?

Comment: Well you need for sure Internet permission in the manifest also can you please post your stacks?

Comment: Yes, I added the permission, but it doesn't work, I edited my question with code. (can I use MediaPlayer with mms?)

Comment: i see you added code but i would also like to see the error the Logcat so i can look whats the error

Comment: I looked in to the logcat the only thing left to try is open the mms with vlc or something similar if that works i dont know man